# Object.defineProperty throws an error because config is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the book JavaScript design Patterns by Addy Osmani, why did he use config like this when It does not work?

```
var defineProp = function ( obj, key, value) {
  config.value = value;
  Object.defineProperty(obj, key, config);
}

var man = Object.create(null);

defineProp( man, 'car', 'Delorean');
defineProp( man, 'dob', '1981');
defineProp( man, 'beard', false);

// As we will see a little later in the book, these methods can even be used for inheritance, as follows:

var driver = Object.create(man); 
defineProp(driver, 'topSpeed', '100mph');
driver.topSpeed // 100mph
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't skip anything? It could just be a typographical error in the book.

Comment: Where do you set value for `config` variable? Where is declaration of `config` variable?

Comment: [Here is an up-to-date version of the book.](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) If you look at that reference, you'll see that the `defineProp()` function looks significantly different.

Comment: The code you posted is missing a declaration of the `config` object.  If that isn't present somewhere else in the code at a higher scope, then what you're showing is a typo.  But, it could be that it's declared at a higher scope and just used by this function (which would not be a great design).  If you search for `defineProp()` in the link Pointy provided, you will see a more proper definition of that function.

Comment: In the .pdf file that I have, config was never declared. Thanks @Pointy for the showing me the latest update.